# Read the values of a txt file that is uploaded on web form

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, file-upload, file-io

I haven't found any good examples of reading through a txt file through a file input type in web forms.

In C#, is it possible to read through a txt file without having the path hardcoded? There must be a dozen examples online where they set the path equal to a string and append the filename onto the end. The problem with this is, I don't know if the user is going to upload it from their desktop, their documents folder, a random folder they created, etc. Is there a way to find the path easily every time?

I was just hoping there was something as simple as putting the values into a 2D array and looping through them to do more validation.

Comment: When you upload a file to a web form, you have a stream and you get the filename. But the webserver will usually not be able to access a local file. Anyway, this question is too broad to be suitable for this site and there are plenty of resources out there about uploading a file.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to know or care about the directory because you will get a `Stream` and you can read from that. Having said that, [HttPostedFileBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) has `FileName` property so you can look into that to see what it provides you. The docs say:

> The name of the file on the client, which includes the directory path.

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase thisPic in this.Request.Files)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(thisPic.InputStream))
        {
            // call methods on reader such as reader.ReadLine() etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some code to show you how to read the file: